# Problem to launch java at Debian: "error while loading shared libraries: libjli.so"

Tags: debian, permissions, java, dynamic-linking

I'm trying to launch java:

```
$ java -version
java: error while loading shared libraries: libjli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

$ ldd /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/java
        linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb779f000)
        libz.so.1 => /usr/lib/libz.so.1 (0xb7780000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i686/cmov/libpthread.so.0 (0xb7767000)
        libjli.so => /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/../lib/i386/jli/libjli.so (0xb7762000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/i686/cmov/libdl.so.2 (0xb775e000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/i686/cmov/libc.so.6 (0xb7603000)
        /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb77a0000
$ ls /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/../lib/i386/jli/
libjli.so
```

But java works under root:

```
$ sudo java -version
java version "1.6.0_18"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.8.7) (6b18-1.8.7-2~lenny1)
OpenJDK Client VM (build 14.0-b16, mixed mode, sharing)
```

UPD:

/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/java is actually my java command:

```
$ type java
java is hashed (/usr/bin/java)
$ ls -l /usr/bin/java
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Jul 14 10:15 /usr/bin/java -> /etc/alternatives/java
$ ls -l /etc/alternatives/java
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 40 Jul 14 10:36 /etc/alternatives/java -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/java
```

UPD2:

I've also tried to set root PATH:

```
$ sudo su
# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
# exit
$ export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
$ java -version
java: error while loading shared libraries: libjli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

UPD3:

I'm tried:

```
# comm -3 <(declare | sort) <(declare -f | sort)
```

under root. But there is no usable environment variables for java.

UPD4:

`strace -f java -version` result: http://dumpz.org/67368/

Comment: Please run `strace -f java -version` and post the output.

Comment: This is strace result: http://dumpz.org/67368/

Answer (score 12):

```
open("$ORIGIN/../lib/i386/jli/tls/i686/sse2/cmov/libz.so.1", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

The executable you're running looks for libraries in an [rpath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rpath) in addition to the normal library search path. The rpath here is `$ORIGIN/../lib/i386/jli:$ORIGIN/../jre/lib/i386/jli`. Normally `$ORIGIN` should be replaced by the location of the executable, here `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin`.

Here, `$ORIGIN` isn't being replaced. The feature is turned off in executables running with extra privileges (setuid, setgid, or setpcap), because otherwise you might be able to inject a different library and so run arbitrary code with elevated privileges. (See [this article](http://blog.tinola.com/?e=7) for a more detailed explanation.) The security issue was discovered relatively recently; in Debian it was fixed in [DSA-2122-1](http://lists.debian.org/debian-security-announce/2010/msg00172.html), so before you upgraded to `libc6-2.7-18lenny6`, your `java` executable would presumably have worked.

The symptom indicates that `java` is running with additional privileges. This is not the case in a normal Debian installation. Make sure that `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/java` is mode 755 and doesn't have any capabilities (`getcap /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/java`, and `setcap -r …` to remove the capabilities if any).

---

*(Original answer, which may be useful if you find that `java` works as root but not as other users, and it does turn out that you're invoking different binaries.)*

My bet is that you have some other `java` version earlier on your `PATH` (`sudo` changes the `PATH`). Check what `type java` says — it's probably some different Java version for which `ldd /path/to/bin/java` reports `libjli.so => not found`.

And I speculate that the reason that this Java version can't find `libjli.so` is that it's looking for it through a rpath (library search path stored in the executable) that doesn't match the way it's installed. If you have the `java` binary in `/some/where/bin/java`, and it has a relative rpath (which is the way of the Sun JDK and OpenJDK), the library should be in `/some/where/lib/i386/jli/libjli.so` (assuming an i386 architecture). If the rpath is absolute, you need to either put `libjli.so` in the exact specified location, or set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to include where `libjli.so` is.

Comment: i'm updated originally post - ldd /path/to/bin/java is actually `type java`

Comment: I'm tried to set root PATH and `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/i386/jli/`, but got the same error.

Comment: Ok, I lost my bet. It seems that your java executable has additional privileges, which is odd.

Answer (score 4):

I downloaded "1.7.0_60" from java.com in `.tar.gz` format and installed it into `/usr/local/jre1.7.0_60`. I then created a hard link to `/usr/local/bin/java` and received the error described above.

Changing the hardlink to a symbolic link fixed the issue.

Short version:

```
$ sudo ln /usr/local/jre1.7.0_60/bin/java /usr/local/bin/java
```

Is bad.

```
$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/jre1.7.0_60/bin/java /usr/local/bin/java
```

Is good.

Answer (score 2):

Try to find the java executable inside the same path as `libjli.so` and use that.

E.g. I found `libjli.so` in `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so`, so I used

```
find /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/ -name "java"
```

and found the executable in `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/java`. Then, I deleted `java` from `/usr/bin` and just symlinked above executable into `/usr/bin`.

Answer (score 2):

If bug is due to using setcap on Java executable, then refer to

[How to get Oracle java 7 to work with setcap cap_net_bind_service+ep](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87978/how-to-get-oracle-java-7-to-work-with-setcap-cap-net-bind-serviceep)
and 
http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=7157699

which answers this question in details.

ps. In our project we had to do

```
sudo setcap cap_net_bind_service=+ep /path/to/java
```

to allow java binary to open tcp/udp ports below 1024. Above java "bug" 7157699 provides quick solution, by adding directory where libjli.so is located into a conf file in /etc/ld.so.conf.d path and then calling ldconfig to re-cache libraries. Assuming Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions on that file. They should look like `0644/-rw-r--r--`. If not, reinstall **`openjdk-6-jre-headless`**, because it would mean someone messed with the permissions.

Comment: `ldd` would report `libjli.so => not found` if it couldn't read the `.so` (at least that's what happens with GLibc 2.11).

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Tshepang's answer, I forced `libjli.so` into the library search path:

```
# find /usr/lib/jvm -name \libjli.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.45/jre/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so

# export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/jre/lib/amd64/jli:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

For reference, my build environment uses github:flexiondotorg/oab-java6 on Ubuntu 10.04/64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

For some odd reason `/usr/bin/java` was no longer pointing to the java installation. No idea how this happened. I confirmed this by running:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Which gave me the following

```
There is only one alternative in link group java (providing /usr/bin/java): /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
Nothing to configure.
update-alternatives: warning: forcing reinstallation of alternative /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java because link group java is broken
update-alternatives: warning: not replacing /usr/bin/java with a link
```

So the solution was to remove the java in `/usr/local/bin` and create a new symlink:

```
$ sudo rm -rf /usr/bin/java
$ sudo ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java /usr/bin/java
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error.

The simplest way to solve it is to simply remove all jdks and jres and also the executable /usr/bin/java, if it's there.

And then reinstall jdk.

It solved the problem for me. While other methods didn't.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone trying to start a Java application from a systemd service and getting the same error, related to the `libjli.so` library, read on.

There is an open bug for this for Fedora currently:

[Bug 1358476 –
SELinux preventing systemd from exec’ing java-based services](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1358476)

Upshot of that is that SELinux is *silently* restricting access to that library. Because there is no AVC denied message, you can't fix it with context, or policy change.

I've found that adding a file `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` that contains the folder of your `libjli.so` file is one workaround:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.161-5.b14.fc26.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/jli/
```

And then run

```
ldconfig
```

But that's pretty messy...

A better option is to use `/bin/bash -c` to launch the Java process in your service file:

```
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "/usr/bin/java -Xmx1024m -jar myApp.jar NONINTERACTIVE"
```

Until the issue is fixed....

Comment: Does it have to be `/bin/bash`? What happens if you use `/bin/sh`?

Comment: @G-Man Did you try it with /bin/sh ? I would guess that would also work but you'd have to try. Please update with how you go with it. Thanks