# How to get Oracle java 7 to work with setcap cap_net_bind_service+ep

Tags: linux, security, java, administration, setcap

I am trying to grant the java executable the right to open ports below 1024 on Linux. Here is the setup

- `/home/test/java` contains the Oracle Server JRE 7.0.25
- CentOS 6.4

Here is what getcap returns

```
[test@centos6 java]$ pwd
/home/test/java

[test@centos6 java]$ getcap bin/java
bin/java = cap_net_bind_service+ep

[test@centos6 java]$ getcap jre/bin/java
jre/bin/java = cap_net_bind_service+ep
```

Trying to execute java gives the following error.

```
[test@centos6 java]$ bin/java
bin/java: error while loading shared libraries: libjli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[test@centos6 java]$ jre/bin/java
jre/bin/java: error while loading shared libraries: libjli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Is it possible to run Java 7_u25 when the binary has been given elevated privileges with setcap, if so how?

[JDK-6919633 : Runtime does not support POSIX File Capabilities (A.K.A. Linux Capabilities)](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6919633)
says that

```
Note: when using the setcap the libraries needed by the java launcher
should be present in /usr/lib or any other "trusted" location that the
runtime loader (rtld) uses to find shared libraries.
```

How do I make the shared libraries trusted?

Answer (score 15):

Until you asked the question I never even heard of this facility in Unix (file capabilities). I found this link which looks to have the solution as to how to make ld.so trust your shared libraries:

- [JDK-7157699 : can not run java after granting posix capabilities](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-7157699)

*excerpt from that post*

> When one is raising the privileges of an executable, the runtime
> loader (rtld), better know as ld.so will not link with libraries in
> untrusted paths. This is the way the ld.so(1) has been designed. If
> one needs to run such an executable, then you have to add that path to
> the trusted paths of ld.so, the following describes how to do so:

```
Fedora 11:
% uname -a
Linux localhost.localdomain 2.6.29.4-167.fc11.i686.PAE #1 SMP Wed May 27 17:28:22 EDT 2009 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

> 

```
% sudo setcap cap_net_raw+epi ./jdk1.7.0_04/bin/java
```

> 

```
% ./jdk1.7.0_04/bin/java -version
./jdk1.7.0_04/bin/java: error while loading shared libraries: libjli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

> Its kaput, Ok we are on the same page now, to fix this, create a file such as > this, with the path to libjli.so

```
% cat /etc/ld.so.conf.d/java.conf
/home/someuser/jdk1.7.0_04/jre/lib/i386/jli
```

> This will add the the pathname to the trusted user path, that ld.so
> will  use, to build its runtime cache, verify if ld.so is seeing it by
> doing this, need to run it as root, and a reboot may be necessary.

```
% ldconfig | grep libjli
libjli.so -> libjli.so
.......
```

> Now test java:

```
% ./jdk1.7.0_04/bin/java -version
java version "1.7.0_04-ea"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_04-ea-b18)
```

> and there you have it.....

#### References

- [POSIX file capabilities: Parceling the power of root](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-posixcap/)
- [This is the Linux kernel capabilities FAQ](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/libs/security/linux-privs/kernel-2.2/capfaq-0.2.txt)
- [capabilities man page](http://linux.die.net/man/7/capabilities)
- [Capability-based security - wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capability-based_security)
- [Using File Capabilities Instead Of Setuid](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Using_File_Capabilities_Instead_Of_Setuid)

Comment: This approach seems to be a system wide change, is there way to restrict the trust on a per user basis so that user foo and bar can have their own different versions of java with different version of libjli.so without running into conflict.

Comment: @ams: you are trusting a program to give the user a capability they usually don't have. This is important: you are trusting program code to not misuse (nor let others misuse) that capability. That is why you have to trust those libraries at a system-wide level.

Comment: @ams You can use the [privbind](https://github.com/JiriHorky/privbind) utility to be able to do that on per-process basis, not per-executable basis.

Answer (score 1):

Just to show the full process to enable Java listenign at port 80 (or any port below 1024):

- For a JAVA_HOME:

  ```
  $> export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/graalvm-ce-java8-20.2.0
  ```
- You should enable the capability to the java binary:

  ```
  $> sudo /sbin/setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=ep' /usr/local/java/graalvm-ce-java8-20.2.0/bin/java
  ```
- After that you will start to get some error when running java:

  ```
  $> java -version
  ./bin/java: error while loading shared libraries: libjli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
  ```
- To fix that you should update `ldconfig`. Just create a `java.conf` file:

  ```
  $> cat /etc/ld.so.conf.d/java.conf 
  /usr/local/java/graalvm-ce-java8-20.2.0/lib/amd64/jli
  /usr/local/java/graalvm-ce-java8-20.2.0/jre/lib/amd64/jli

  $> java -version
  ```
- Now java works:

  ```
  $> java -version
  openjdk version "1.8.0_262"
  ...
  ```