# How to set local shared library path after setting file capabilities on Debian?

Tags: debian, capabilities, shared-library

I have a custom application which comes with its own *libstdc++.so.6* and it requires *cap_net_admin* and *cap_net_raw* to work properly.
Before I set file capabilities it starts without problems but when I set:

```
/sbin/setcap cap_net_admin,cap_net_raw+pie /path/to/customapp
```

it gives the following error:

```
./customapp: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.19' not found (required by ./customapp)
```

When I do `readelf -d` it shows that it is looking for libraries at the correct location:

```
0x0000000f (RPATH)                      Library rpath: [$ORIGIN/lib]
```

and `ldd ./customapp` shows the same:

```
libstdc++.so.6 => /path/to/./lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0xb75ed000)
```

I followed the advice given [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87978/how-to-get-oracle-java-7-to-work-with-setcap-cap-net-bind-serviceep) and added new shared library path to `ld.so(1)`:

```
echo "/path/to/lib" > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/customapp.conf && ldconfig
```

I tried this on Ubuntu 14.04 and it works well there so why doesn't it work on Debian?

OS: Debian GNU/Linux 7.6 (wheezy)
`uname -a`: Linux debsrv 3.2.0-4-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 3.2.60-1+deb7u3 i686 GNU/Linux

Comment: I presume you've checked `man ld.so` on both systems? Some systems ignore $ORIGIN for setuid executables for security reasons, and it's easy to see how that could be extended to capabilities. Perhaps there's a policy or configuration setting to control this?

Comment: You're right. @ORIGIN doesn't get expanded for executables with file capabilities [(1)](http://blog.tinola.com/?e=7).

Comment: So the real questions are: 
1. why a difference on these two platforms (Ubuntu vs Debian)?
2. why weren't you able to fix this with ld.so.conf.d?
Different versions of ld.so or kernel perhaps? Or different default system settings that somehow affect this behavior? I would expect the man page to correctly reflect the behavior. If not, that's a bug.

Comment: Anyone know how to solve this?