# Which Privileges Should Assign To Create Raw Sockets

Tags: fedora, root, socket, ping

I want to run an ICMP command to ping an IP Adress at Java:

```
InetAddress.getByAddress("XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX".getBytes()).isReachable(1000);
```

However there is a security restriction that:

```
Normal users are allowed to create raw sockets.
```

So I can not run it. I don't want to run my application as root. So, which privileges should I assign to the user that runs my application for CAP_NET_RAW capability?

Comment: **[From this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9772068/raw-socket-access-as-normal-user-on-linux-2-4)** it sounds like you have to **[setuid on the executable](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/166817/using-the-setuid-bit-properly)** (and the executable must be owned by root) so it can either create the socket or setpcap on itself at runtime (I think CAP_NET_RAW applies to processes, not executables).  Unfortunately, I'm not sure about the possibilities for a java program this way, since they're not strictly executables.

Comment: @goldilocks could you write it as answer?

Comment: No, because I think I am wrong about CAP_NET_RAW not being being applicable to executables.  However, it looks like WRT java you would have to set that on the runtime engine (`java`) itself, and there are some major PITA issues that come along with that if you are using, e.g., an Oracle install with libs outside of standard places like `/usr/lib`.  See here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87978/how-to-get-oracle-java-7-to-work-with-setcap-cap-net-bind-serviceep

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment to your answer, you have to set the capability to the Java executable. Here is a working example:

```
sudo setcap cap_net_raw+epi /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-19/bin/java
```

(replace path with path to your Java executable)